# iOS - Drawing pencil stroke for iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm working on a `Drawing application` where I need to achieve `pencil effect` similar to `Apple notes app`.

So I subclasses the UIView and write the following code.

```
CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
}

@interface DrawingView () {
    CGPoint currentPoint;
    CGPoint previousPoint1;
    CGPoint previousPoint2;
    CGMutablePathRef path;
}

@end

@implementation DrawingView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
    CGMutablePathRef subpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(subpath);

    CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath);
    CGPathRelease(subpath);

   [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:bounds];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0f);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This works fine and it produces the output like the following.

[image]

But I need the output like the following picture. Similar to Apple Notes app.

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Any leads to this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the pencil texture and set this image as your CGContext stroke color.

[image]

```
private var pencilTexture = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pencil_texture")!)
ctx.setStrokeColor(pencilTexture.cgColor)
```

[image]